# How would I inline the bool operator overloads, so it can be defined in the .cpp file? (C++)

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading

So I have my Vector3 class, and I want to know if I can inline the (<, >, ...) (this is micro-optimization though.)

I've messed around for around an hour, but couldn't figure it out.

```
// Vector3.h
#pragma once

struct Vector3 {
    // ...

    // do I forward declare with inline or leave it like this?
    // do I need to define two args?
    bool operator<(const Vector3& other);
    
    // ...
};
```

```
// Vector3.cpp

#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include "Vector3.h"

using namespace std;

Vector3:: Vector3(double x, double y, double z):
        X(x), Y(y), Z(z) {
    
    this->Magnitude = this->GetMagnitude();
            
    if (this->Magnitude != 1) {
        this->Unit = new Vector3(
            this->X / this->Magnitude,
            this->Y / this->Magnitude,
            this->Z / this->Magnitude
        );
    }
}

// how can I inline this, do I need to use this, or an argument passed in first?
inline bool Vector3::operator<(const Vector3& other) {
    return (
        this->X < other.X &&
        this->Y < other.Y &&
        this->Z < other.Z
    );
}

// ...
```

Comment: To inline a function its definition must be visible. If it is located in .cpp then only within that .cpp it can be inlined. To make functions inlinable you should put them in headers.

Comment: The role of the `inline` keyword is different than you might think. You don't need to remark a function as `inline` to encourage the compiler to do this. The compiler will decide this on its own. Even if you move the implementation of your operator into the header, it's not necessary to remark it explicitly as `inline`. [inline specifier](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/inline): _A function defined entirely inside a class/struct/union definition, whether it's a member function or a non-member friend function, is implicitly an inline function._